# Display MySQL errors Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla2.5

How can I display if there is any error after executing last query by `query()` or `execute()` in Joomla 2.5?

CUrrently I am using `var_dump($wsr_db_object->stderr(true));` but this does not show MySQL errors. It only helps you that query was executed or not?

Edit:

Here is how I am running my

```
    $rw_db_object->setQuery($insert_rw_cats);
    $rw_db_object->query();
    var_dump($wsr_db_object->stderr(true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Joomla has a built in dump method like so:

```
$query->dump();
```

When writing your queries, please refer to the [Joomla documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase)

Hope this helps

### Update:

```
$rw_db_object->setQuery($insert_rw_cats);
$rw_db_object->query();
$rw_db_object->dump();
```

Comment: `$query->dump();` or `$db->dump()`

Comment: The first one: `$query->dump();`. If you have used a different variable for your query, then you will need to change `$query` to whatever you have used.

Comment: Can you please add your full database query to your question so I can take a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63313/discussion-between-user3709682-and-lodder).

Comment: Sorry but I did not see any output from this function .. I also tried by MisTyping my query to check if it DUMPs any error.. but nothing happened.

Comment: Can you please provide me link to the doc of `dump()` for just PHP or Joomla

Comment: http://api.joomla.org/cms-2.5/classes/JDatabaseQuery.html#method_dump ... Ok it looks as if your database query is pulling no data. As requested, please show your **FULL** database query. By that, I mean every single bit of code you're using for it.

Comment: FULL DB QUERY??? query is simple `SELECT * FROM RW_CATS`

And I have another one INSERT query that INSERTs two rows.

I tried for both of them ...

Comment: It may very well be something simple like `SELECT * FROM RW_CATS` but there is something wrong with it. If I am to help you, I need to see the full query else I cannot help you. If you have read the Joomla documentation on database queries, then there should not be a problem

Comment: SELECT * FROM `sc_cats` WHERE date_modified > '" . DATE_TO_CHECK . "'

Comment: define('DATE_TO_CHECK', date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime('-1 days')));

Comment: `FROM sc_cats` << Is `sc` the database table prefix? If not, then you need to define it like so: `#__sc_cats`

Comment: query is executed successfully dear...

but dump() shows nothing.

Even I tried putting TYPO error deliberately in that query ... Query was not executed as I did not get results. But `dump()` again showed nothing